# When images are imported from my database and outputted in a gallery they become blurry?

Tags: html, css, image

[Blurry Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWmg1.png)
[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFbhn.jpg)

I have a simple image upload function in php. It takes an image and uploads it to the database as a blob. When i call the image into the gallery it becomes blurry. Is there a way around this i have heard of people using GD etc. My code is below for the upload and the calling.

gallery.php

```
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:1300px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;">
              <?php 
              $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM tbl_images"); 

              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
            ?>
            <div>
                <?php echo'<img width="100%" height:"100%" class="img-fluid" src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['name']) . '"  />' ?>

            </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

uploadFile.php

```
            <?php   
 if(isset($_POST["insert"]))  
 {  
      $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));  
      $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images(name) VALUES ('$file')";  
      if(mysqli_query($connection, $query))  
      {  
           echo '<script>alert("Image Inserted into Database")</script>';  
      }  
 } 

 ?>
```

Comment: Can you post an example image, give us the raw file and a screenshot of how it looks on the page

Comment: The image might be just smaller than your fixed size defined in your css code. If you scale up an image it will look blurry

Comment: Simply remove the `width="100%" height:"100%"`  from the `img` tag.

Comment: if i remove the width and height its not the full screen size and i have attached the blurry image and normal image above

Comment: i understand the image is scaled up but i need a way to make it clear

Comment: There is no way to properly display a 960px × 662px image on a common FHD (1920 x 1080) display. The result will always suck.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `image-rendering: pixelated` CSS style to your `img` element.